# How to populate the Content column in the wp_bp_activity table in the BuddyPress database using Gravity

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, buddypress, gravityforms, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I want to populate the Content column in the wp_bp_activity table in the BuddyPress database using Gravity. What meta should I use for this purpose? In the user registration gravity plugin, there is a place where you can associate the user meta. What meta should be there in this section to be able to link the Gravity form to this column? So that by linking to the Gravity form, the BuddyPress status is created through this column.

---[Database table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSTCT.jpg)

- [user registration gravity forms addon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvFDH.png)

Many Thanks

I want to fill the Content column in the wp_bp_activity table in the BuddyPress database through Gravity. What meta should I use for this? There is a place in the user registration gravity plugin where you can link the user meta. What meta should be present in this section to be able to connect the Gravity form to this column? So that by connecting to the Gravity form, the BuddyPress status is created through this column.